# Fire base Error android

Tags: java, android, firebase

i am getting this error

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f070040
     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5454)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5046)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4986)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:177)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1495)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5930)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f070040
     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:553)
     at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:639)
     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzah.getString(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions.fromResource(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzbu(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
     at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1737)
     at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1712)
     at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5451)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5046) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4986) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:177) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1495) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5930) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

i've application id in gradle,as suggested by answer to one other question
and only use one line of firebase(it dont go in oncreate method BTW of main activity)
if possible tel me reasons why this error may arise,if you cant find exact reason to problem
thanks in advance

```
firebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
```

Comment: `Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f070040` typically means you have used an integer value in place of a string or an existing resource id

Comment: The line you shared is certainly not raising the exception. @cricket_007 has the most likely culprit. But without seeing the code that raises the error, there's not much more we can do.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Could it be from the `values.xml` from the Play Services? Based upon `at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzah.getString`

Comment: Could you run `./gradlew :app:assembleDebug` at the command line and then provide the contents of `app/build/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values.xml`

Comment: It might be as simply as cleaning the project and rebuilding.  Sometimes resources get out of whack in incremental builds.

Comment: thanx @cricket_007  it was at values.xml